# SQLite Cursor crashes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

i have a problem with my SQLite class. In fact, i was learning how to setting up (update and read) a database on android and I successfully wrote on the database, but when i try to read the informations and display them on the screen, my application just crashes.
I searched the problem and found that the cause of the crash is the Cursor. I commented the cursor's method, so if someone can help me with that, i would be thankful.

This my Database class.

```
    package com.example.sqlprogramming;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseClass {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id"; 
public static final String KEY_NAME = "person_name";
public static final String KEY_RATE = "person_rate";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb"; 
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable"; 
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; 

private Dhelper ourHelperdb; 
private final Context ourContext; 
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase; 
private static class Dhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public Dhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        KEY_NAME + "VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + 
        KEY_RATE + "VARCHAR NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
public DatabaseClass(Context c){
    ourContext = c; 
}
public DatabaseClass open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelperdb = new Dhelper(ourContext); 
    ourDatabase = ourHelperdb.getWritableDatabase();
    return this; 
}
public void close(){
    ourHelperdb.close();
}
public long addEntry(String personName, String personHotness) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, personName);
    cv.put(KEY_RATE, personHotness);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
            //HERE IS MY PROBLEM WITH THE CURSOR 
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_RATE};
    String result = "hello"; 
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    int iRowId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iRate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_RATE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRowId) + " " + c.getString(iName) +" " + c.getString(iRate) + "\n";
    }

    c.close();
    return result;
}
    }
```

And this Class call the Database Class and should take informations from database to display it on the screen.

```
package com.example.sqlprogramming;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLview extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_sqlview);
    TextView textInfo = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvSQLinfo); 
    DatabaseClass info = new DatabaseClass(this);
    info.open(); 
    String _data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    textInfo.setText(_data);
}
}
```

Thank you again. 
I'll post stacktrace and logcat soon.

Here is my Logcat/Stacktrace

```
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221): I got an error here : 
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such     column: person_name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id AS _id, person_name, person_rate FROM peopleTable
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at                 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at com.example.sqlprogramming.DatabaseClass.getData(DatabaseClass.java:75)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at com.example.sqlprogramming.SQLview.onCreate(SQLview.java:14)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 20:08:12.378: E/Curosr!(1221):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Always post the full stack trace with crashing errors.

Comment: add here logcat please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create statement is missing a few spaces. Try using:

```
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
    KEY_NAME + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + 
    KEY_RATE + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);");
```

According to your current statement, your last two column names become `person_nameVARCHAR` and `person_rateVARCHAR`

Comment: That's what i tried, but that doesn't work, and the logcat message is the same, thanks.

Comment: @R00t You will have to uninstall and then reinstall the app for the new create statement to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading, you need to use:

```
ourDatabase = ourHelperdb.getReadableDatabase();
```

When you open your DB, you are setting it to write.

(That's my first guess, post stack trace).

Here's a working example from some of my code on how to read a cursor:

```
mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor c = mDb.query("Timesheets", new String[] {
        KEY_TIMESHEETS_ROWID + " AS _id", KEY_TIMESHEETS_DESCRIPTION,
        KEY_TIMESHEETS_TITLE, KEY_TIMESHEETS_DATE_START,
        KEY_TIMESHEETS_DATE_END, KEY_TIMESHEETS_INVOICED,
        KEY_TIMESHEETS_PROJECTID }, "timesheet_id = ?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(timesheetId) }, null, null, null);

c.moveToFirst();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Timesheet timesheet = new Timesheet();

while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {

    timesheet.setTimesheetId(c.getInt(0));

    // ...

    c.moveToNext();
}

c.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I add the getReadableDatabase(); nethod to the DBHelper and used the cursor as your example, but that doesn't work, it still crashing when i'm trying to read data.

Comment: The database returned `getWritableDatabase()` can be read from as well. Using `getReadableDatabase()` is not a requirement.